# How to set button inside input?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to place button in my input

I tried to set position relative for the form and absolute for the button and changed left/top. But in that fields i must to large values for well done result (i set left 600px for place button in input, so it confuses me)

I want like that: [image]

*Is there a way to do this for flex display?*

```css
form {
    padding: 4rem 0;
    position: relative;
}
input[type=text] {
    background: #fff;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 0.7rem;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbce;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: #3a3d4b;
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    background: #6fc754;
    padding: 0.6rem 1rem;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 25px;
    left: 600px;
    top:5px;
}
```

```html
 <form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter text">
  <button>Send Invite</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It is most likely a hack: a `div` encapsulate the form (`input` and `button`). The input has invisible border and the border you see is the border of the wrapping `div`

Comment: do you want to say that i need to encapsulate form in div block?

Comment: I barely understood the answer, i guess you want to have the button inside the input, you must ser position:relative to you input instead the form for better handling position, than set right on the button.

Comment: You could try something like an inputgroup from Bootstrap with a button. I can make you an example if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can NOT change the HTML structure, then well you have fixed width of 500px so ofcourse you will have to have some nasty calculations to position it.

If you had used percentages would've been more easy

On top of that you have paddings ( that differ from the input to the button )

So firstly, `left` of the button should be `calc(500px + 1.4rem);` where `500px` is the width of the input and `1.4rem` is from the `left/right padding` of `0.7rem` which the `input` has. Now the button is positioned right after the input. Now move it to the left with 100% of its width.

Second, the bottom should be `bottom: 4.2rem` because of `form` padding `top/bottom` of `4rem` and then `0.2rem` because the padding of input is `0.7rem` and padding of button is `0.6rem` so `0.1 *2` smaller ( on Y axis ) .

```css
form {
  padding: 4rem 0;
  position: relative;
}

input[type=text] {
  background: #fff;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 0.7rem;
  border: 1px solid #cbcbce;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: #3a3d4b;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  background: #6fc754;
  padding: 0.6rem 1rem;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  left: calc(500px + 1.4rem);
  bottom: 4.2rem;
  transform: translateX(-100%)
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter text">
  <button>Send Invite</button>
</form>
```

Comment: @Nick are you sure ? https://jsfiddle.net/omqyedp5/ need some word-breaks but the position is still the same

Comment: Yes. If the button text wraps, the positioning gets messed up as well.

Comment: @Nick Again. Are you sure ? https://jsfiddle.net/omqyedp5/2/  added `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: Well of course the input will be smaller on mobile screens. But that's not what the OP asked. We cannot answer a question and cover all the possible scenarios the OP will use the code in. Especially when there is just a simple sample code without any specific context

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. There is no error:

```css
form {
    padding: 4rem 0;
    position: relative;
    display: table;
}
input[type=text] {
 box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #fff;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 0.7rem 115px 0.7rem 0.7rem;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbce;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: #3a3d4b;
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    background: #6fc754;
    padding: 0.6rem 1rem;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 25px;
    right: 4px;
    transform: translateY(2.5px);
}
```

```html
 <form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter text">
  <button>Send Invite</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you need to wrap them in a `div` that has a `position: relative;` css property to it.

```css
form {
    padding: 4rem 0;
    position: relative;
}

.relative {
position: relative;
}

input[type=text] {
    background: #fff;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 0.7rem;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbce;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: #3a3d4b;
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    background: #6fc754;
    padding: 0.7rem 1rem;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 25px;
    right: 141px;
    top:1px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="relative">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter text">
    <button>Send Invite</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This is where you will need to use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to make it look the way you want. Or use percentage instead of `px` for sizing and placement.